# Capistrano error when change repository using git

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I have a simple deployment via capistrano from a Git repository.

I wanted to change the repository I was working with so I basically just changed

> set :repository,  "git@github.com:new_repository"

But i get the following error when deploying:

fatal: Could not parse object '9cfb...'.

The problem goes away once I change

> set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

to

> set :deploy_via, :copy

I also tried deploy:cleanup but I get the following error:

*`deploy:cleanup' is only run for servers matching {:except=>{:no_release=>true}}, but no servers matched*

Any idea how could i get remote_cache working again?

Thansk!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capistrano deploy fails after I changed the repository URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358238/capistrano-deploy-fails-after-i-changed-the-repository-url)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With capistrano 3, to avoid deleting the repo folder :

1. Change the repo URL in your `config/deploy.rb`, as the OP already did
2. SSH to your server inside and change the remote URL of the git repo :

   ```
   ssh user@server.com  
   # Go the capistrano deploy root
   cd /capistrano/deploy/root/folder  
   # Go inside the folder names *repo*
   cd repo  
   # Manually change the git remote
   git remote set-url origin ...
   ```

Answer (score 11):

**Capistrano < 3**

Fix it in ***./shared/cached-copy/.git/config*** from deployment folder of your server.

OR ugly way do this:

Remove the ***shared/cached-copy*** from deployment folder of your server.

**Capistrano > 3**

Fix it in ***./repo/config*** from deployment folder of your server.

**Learn How to fix similar issues**

It is caused as your server files are referring to old repo so you have to find and fix it.
Do this to find matches in files:

```
cd /path/to/your/project
grep -r OLD_REPO_NAME ./
```

Now you see all files including your OLD_REPO_NAME . 
If they are matched in your release folder or current, you dont need to care for fixing them. But you should fix all configs.

Answer (score 6):

you can just change the git url in

```
shared/cached-copy/.git/config
```

Answer (score 6):

Additional info for Capistrano 3 users. Capistrano will create a folder `repo`. So the structure looks like this:

```
current -> /var/www/preview/releases/20140612212305
releases
repo
revisions.log
shared
```

When you change the `:repo_url` in `deploy.rb` you can safely remove the `repo` folder and run the deployment. The folder will be created again. The reason why you have to do this step is because in repo/config is the old remote url.

Comment: Worked for me (deleting the repo folder)

Answer (score 3):

ssh to your production server and delete the content of your shared/cache folder. The git ref stored in there is not valid anymore so it won't work.

Comment: Hi Mathieu. I removed everything inside shared/cached-copy and got the same error, then I removed it and got this error: _ERROR: Repository not found_

Comment: Yeah you need the folder for sure. It usually works for me. I've always fixed that issue the same way. Let me see

Comment: Thanks! I've been struggling for a while with this problem without any results.

Comment: These doesn't work with Capistrano 3, change the url in repo/config file. Shared/cache folder doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Just add task into deploy.rb to sync it automagically.

`$ cap admin:fix_repo`

```
  namespace :admin do
    desc 'Fix repo'
    task :fix_repo, :roles => :web do
      run "cd #{shared_path}/cached-copy && git remote set-url origin #{repository}"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

As related to this [thread](https://coderwall.com/p/4k1lja/fixing-capistrano-3-deployments-after-a-repository-change), after updated your `deploy.rb` with

`set :repository, "git@github.com:new_repository"`

go to your server with ssh deploy-user, then `cd Old_repository/repo`and `sudo vim config`

You'll find the line
`url = git@github.com:username/old_repository.git` and you have to rename it with `url = git@github.com:username/new_repository.git`

Don't forget to delete the Old_repository folder on your server, or just rename it before in New_repository folder !